# OpenVPN sans port forwarding on unfriendly networks

Tags: openvpn, nat, udp

I have a problem. I'm about to move onto campus right in the middle of the semester. For a student, I have a complicated network setup where all of my systems are reliant on NAS and all of them VPN back to home while I'm on campus.

I use ClearOS as my OpenVPN server(s).

My Home network has 40 mbps down, 5 mbps up.

My School network has a lot down, and a lot up.

My school Apartment network - I don't know yet.

I can't tell how separate the school networks are. Since I can't access the apartment network yet, I need to consider it as a separate network.

Currently my home network hosts an OpenVPN server and a lot of NAS that has all of my personal info hosted in a central location. I access this server with 5 different devices. All connections are school->home.

My school will not forward ports.

I plan on deploying an openVPN server on the school apartment network and leaving one at home as well.

I do not want to do the following:
Apartment->Home
School->Home
With the home network passing traffic between my devices at my apartment and out on campus. It'd saturate the upload bandwidth pretty quickly.

What I want is something like this:
School->Apartment
Apartment->Home OR School->Home

I run into an issue because port forwarding doesn't happen on the apartment network

But, I know that there's a way to use my Home network to facilitate a connection between my School and Apartment networks.

I've looked at this:
samy.pl/pwnat/ and it looks close to an exploit. Since this school's infosec division is really active, there's an incredibly strict policy about shenanigans of any sort outside of test networks.

So I've started looking at UDP hole punching, resources.infosecinstitute.com/udp-hole-punching/

I've found a program that claims to do what I need it to do, but doesn't really give me much confidence due to the typos in it, a google code project called punchVPN

And I've found another piece of VPN software, tinc, that might work for me. I don't like the idea of swapping to unfamiliar VPN software.

I'm slammed and don't have time to experiment. This has to go immediately into production. Next week I'm looking at an exam Tuesday, another Wednesday, a project due Thursday and a video game due Friday. I move Saturday and need this working Saturday night! Therefore, if someone else has done this before and has a working solution I need to hear from you.

To summarize, networks A and B are NATted, network C is not. How do I use C to get A and B to connect using OpenVPN in a way that doesn't alert/anger my IT overlords or direct all traffic between A and B through C?

Bonus points if there's a way to skip UDP and spoof TCP 443.